# Sorting Array Perl (part two)

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

Right, so I've gotten some help but need some more, I have a pretty good understanding on how to sort an array alphabetically. But now I need to sort it numerically. It's probably a syntax error near "`my @test = (sort {items{$a}} <=> {items{$b}} @menu)"`

Had it been a hash with two keys I would have a solution, but since this array contains three categories it becomes difficult for me. Obviously looking for some help along with an explanation as possible as I'm eager to learn.
Thank you!

```
my @test = (sort {price{$a} <=> {price{$b}} @menu)
```

Comment: Also if someone could point me to some reading that explains it would be very appreciated, as my luck with google on this topic seems exhausted.

Comment: ad google, try: _perl sort array of hashes by multiple values_ and check first NN links.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `item{$a}`. It looks like you are trying get some value from hash `item` which is not a hash, of course.

```
my @test = sort { $a->{price} <=> $b->{price} } @menu;
```

You can sort according more than one field as well

```
my @test = sort {
           $a->{price} <=> $b->{price}
        or $a->{color} cmp $b->{color}
        or $b->{items} cmp $a->{items} # note reverse order
    } @menu;
```

Comment: This is honestly just plain annyoing. I swear to god I've tried that exact syntax on price earlier but it did not return the right result. However now it does.. Thank you!

Comment: @pubba Note the difference between `cmp` (for strings) and `<=>` (for numbers).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to order by prize:

```
my @test = sort { $a->{prize} <=> $b->{prize} } @menu;
```

and in descending order, just change $a and $b:

```
my @test = sort { $b->{prize} <=> $a->{prize} } @menu;
```